# Successfully codesigned app failed to pass Gatekeeper

Tags: macos, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I am trying to sign my application with codesign command line tool:

```
codesign --deep -v -f -s "Developer ID Application: Xxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx (XXXXXXXXXX)" ./MyApp.app
```

The result is seemed to be success:

```
./MyApp.app: signed app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64) [co.mycompany.myapp]
```

On my friend`s Mac the system assures us that everything is OK:

```
$ codesign -vv --deep-verify ./MyApp.app 
./MyApp.app: valid on disk
./MyApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

$ spctl --assess --type execute --verbose ./MyApp.app 
./MyApp.app: accepted
```

But I still getting that weird message box on executing the App:

"MyApp.app" can`t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed. Your security preferences allow installation only apps from the Mac App Store and identified developers.

What am I doing wrong? How to get rid of that weird Gatekeeper message box?

Other details (on my friend`s Mac):

```
$ codesign -dvvv ./MyApp.app 
Executable=.../MyApp
Identifier=co.mycompany.myapp
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=3983 flags=0x0(none) hashes=119+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=52ef9b732b1bbde8a6ec48ca5c951c25d1daee61
CandidateCDHash sha256=eec891344210e1a3dce69900bfbb18e69efc1247
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=eec891344210e1a3dce69900bfbb18e69efc1247
Signature size=8927
Authority=Developer ID Application: Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (XXXXXXXXXX)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=06 Feb 2017 08:15:35
Info.plist entries=9
TeamIdentifier=YVWF5WN7EA
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=22
Internal requirements count=1 size=176
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: The problem was found with the help of Console.app application. @executable_path was wrong for a dylib used. The solution:

install_name_tool -id libantlr4-runtime.dylib MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libantlr4-runtime.dylib 

install_name_tool -change libantlr4-runtime.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libantlr4-runtime.dylib MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/AdCelWizard

/usr/bin/codesign --deep --force --sign "Developer ID Application: Myname Mysurname(YYYYYYYYYY)" /Users/myname/Documents/MyApp.app